Redux Toolkit with createSelector not memoizing
I have form like so

It has a parent-child relationship. In the RTK slice, it looks like this:
application
-> personList (array of person objects)
--> assetList (array of asset objects)
Example JSON:
{
 application: {
  personList: [
   {
    id,
    fname, 
    lname,
    personFormStatus: { isValid, isDirty},
    assetFormStatus: { isValid, isDirty},
    assetList: [
     {
      type,
      subtype,
      amount,
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
}

And then I have 2 components, 1 per fieldgroup:
const PersonFormComponent = () => {}

const AssetFormComponent = () => {}

I have created a selector in the appSlice.tsx:
export const selectPeopleUniqueIdAndAssetFormStatus = createSelector(
  (state) => {
    console.log('inside inputSelectors');
    return state.application.personList;
  },
  (personList) => {
    console.log('inside combiner');
    return personList.map((p) => ({
      assetFormStatus: p.assetFormStatus,
      id: p.id,
    }));
  }
);

Inside the AssetFormCompnent which doesn't memoize, it keeps recalculating (even though the updates are in the Person names in the PersonFormComponent):
const AssetFormComponent = () => {
 const peopleIdsAndFormStatus = useSelector(
      selectPeopleUniqueIsAndAssetFormStatus
  );
 
}

But if I pass equalityFn in AssetFormCompnent then it does memoize (even though the updates are in the Person names in the PersonFormComponent):
const AssetFormComponent = () => {
 const peopleIdsAndFormStatus = useSelector(
      selectPeopleUniqueIsAndAssetFormStatus, (oldv,newv) => _.isEqual(oldv,newv)
  );
 
}

Can you please let me know if this is appropriate to use deepEquality, because I would have thought the createSelector is memoizing it already?

This question is similar to: When should I use a custom equality function in useSelector()?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Arkellys thanks for the comment- I have updated the question to add more specific question. I read the suggested question/answer link you provided but my scenario is about parent-child and how to avoid rerenders in the child component when changes are in the parent fields in redux state, hope that clarifies it

Your code doesn't appear to be correct, your selectPeopleUniqueIdAndAssetFormStatus selector function isn't being called. I'm pretty sure your selectPeopleUniqueIsAndAssetFormStatus selector function is correctly memoizing its value, but the problem is the anonymous selector function the UI is using. Since an array is returned the shallow equality function is necessary to get the useSelector hook to work like you are expecting. In fact you don't need the anonymous selector function, selectPeopleUniqueIsAndAssetFormStatus already expects to consume the Redux state as an argument.
I suspect you are actually doing something like this:
const peopleIdsAndFormStatus = useSelector(
  (state: RootState) => selectPeopleUniqueIsAndAssetFormStatus(state)
);

But this is unnecessary, pass selectPeopleUniqueIsAndAssetFormStatus directly as the selector function:
const peopleIdsAndFormStatus = useSelector(
  selectPeopleUniqueIsAndAssetFormStatus
);


Thanks yes, I have accidently added the '(state) =>...' and the 2nd version you provided is how i am using it - I have updated the question to reflect this corrected version. I am using the lodash isEqual which is the deepEquality, I tried the shallowEqual from redux but that isn't working as expected, since the assetFormStatus is an object; I was hoping to avoid the equalityFn as I feel like I am doing / using the createSelector incorrectly and not memoizing it correctly?

@CarlosJaimeC.DeLeon So, this doesn't quite address your question then yet? If not, can you create a running CodeSandbox demo that reproduces the issue you describe that we can inspect live? I don't see any overt issue in just that one selector, but we can't see what else is going on in your code around the code you've shared. In the 7-8 years I've worked with React/Redux I can't recall any times I needed to use any equality function with the useSelector hook, it's quite an edge case IMO, and basically only when you don't use memoized selectors.

"@Drew Reese" not yet, I was hoping to get advice how to avoid using equalityFn. Yes I can create a codesanbox, will create one soon :)
